# Getting 'Server is at 0.0.0.0' on serial monitor - in webserver

Tags: server, arduino, arduino-uno

I bought a new Arduino Ethernet Shield and hooked it to the Arduino Uno.
I am trying to set the IP address of the device to 192.168.1.177 tried File-> Examples -> Ethernet-> Webserver.
When I upload this - I get a "server is a 0.0.0.0'message in serial monitor !

My IP is set to 192.168.1.177 and setup a mac address of 0xB8, 0x27, 0xEB, 0x98, 0x46, 0x61 in the webserver code.
Appreciate any help in setting this IP address. ( I tried other combinations as well )
The Arduino Ethernet shield is mounted on the Arduino Uno, and connections are lined up .

Comment: Wait, you're trying to set the address of the device to the same address as your computer?

Answer (score 1):

i fix this problem by pressing firmly the shield to the board

Answer (score 0):

This can manifest from many different causes. I ran into this and figured out that in my case, my the USB port + cable were not allowing sufficient power to the Ethernet chip.

I have 3 cables, 6in, 3ft, and 6ft. Only the 6" one had sufficiently low voltage drop to power the shield.

I honestly couldn't believe it, but there was a 0.1V drop between the 6in and the 6ft cables. When plugged into A USB 3.0 port with the Arduino loaded, I measured ~4.5V for the working 6in cable vs ~4.4V for the non-working 6ft cable.

I have 3 types of USB ports: 1.1, 2.0, and 3.0. Only the USB 3.0 ports provided enough power to power the shield. Thus for my case, I had to use the shortest USB cable on the 3.0 port.

When the Arduino's 5V rail was sufficiently sagging, the 3.3 Linear Regulator entered dropout mode and on all the non-working configurations I saw ~3.1V on the Ethernet shield's 3.3V rail, which is apparently sufficient to cause this symptom.